# linux id no_squash_root

Tags: linux, setuid, usergroups

The linux 'id' command reports on groups=
that process belongs to. When and how does this get filled in?

I'm writing an suid/sgid program and it seems that the groups never get filled in for my process and perhaps just coincidentially, but the permissions inregards to an nfs mounted file system don't work correctly for it either (by the way, I've played with no_root_squash and that didn't help)

Comment: Perhaps you could post some code and/or shell transcript showing exactly what you're seeing that is different from where you expect?  Does your program work correctly if not on an NFS file system?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, the supplementary groups are set by `login`.

If you want to set them yourself, you'll need the functions `getgrouplist()` and `setgroups()` from `<grp.h>` - note that you'll need to be root to call `setgroups()` successfully.

Comment: Note that these functions - and initgroups() - are all outside the scope of the POSIX standard.  They are not all universally available on all Unix-like platforms; specifically, the `getgrouplist()` function is not available on Solaris, for instance.  Also, hacking your own 'getgrouplist()' is expensive; you have to read the entire group 'file' (database) because the raw /etc/group file does not provide the 'inverted index' structure needed to answer the question 'which groups does user X belong to' more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, the setgroups() was pretty much the answer. However, I ended up using initgroups() which worked really well. The call was made before I did the setuid away from root.

Found this in the man pages
NAME
       initgroups - initialize the supplementary group access list

SYNOPSIS
       #include 
       #include

```
   int initgroups(const char *user, gid_t group);
```

Apparently if the groups come from LDAP, you NEED to do this in order to get them filled in properly.

Answer (score 0):

- Multiple group membership is normally set at login but not used much. SOP often is to give each user their own group.
- Network file systems typically don't respect local client root privs.